# How can I add labels to a pie chart, when using an array without named entries

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I wrote a javascript program that produces a pie chart using d3.js.

This works fine, however I am not able to add labels to the chart.

The data I am using has the following structure:

```
    [["country", "percentage"], ["country", "percentage"],...]
```

or as an example:

```
     [["A", "0.5"], ["AUS", "0.3"],....]
```

The graphing works fine, but I get no labels to display.

Any help would be appreciated.

here is an excerpt of the code:

```
    var updatePie = function () {

                var width = 480,
                    height = 480,
                    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;



                var labelr = radius + 30;
                var formatPercent = d3.format(",.2%");
                var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(["A", "AUS", "B", 
                         "BG", "BR", "CDN", 
                         "CH", "CN", "CO", 
                         "CZ", "D", "DK", "E", 
                         "EST", "ET", "F", 
                         "FIN", "GB", "I", 
                         "IL", "IRL", "J", 
                         "N", "NL", "NZ", 
                         "RUS", "S", "UAE", 
                         "USA", "ZA"])
                .range(["#bac5ca", "#7b95a7", "#526f8b",
                        "#454c57", "#323540", "#a17d48",
                        "#5e747d", "#405666", "#2a2e34",
                        "#1f2127", "#5c482b", "#c7d0d4",
                        "#94a9b8", "#6f8aa3", "#616c7c",
                        "#505669", "#b49569", "#8a9ca3",
                        "#57768b", "#41576d", "#363c45",
                        "#292b33", "#7e623a", "#d5dbdf",
                        "#adbdca", "#90a6ba", "#848e9c",
                        "#747b90", "#454c57", "#c6af8c",
                       ]), svg;
                function graph(_selection) {
                    _selection.each(function(_data) {   

                        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                        .value(function(d) { return d[1]; })
                        .sort(null);

                        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                        .innerRadius(radius - 100)
                        .outerRadius(radius - 50);

                        if (!svg){
                            svg = d3.select(this).append("svg")
                                .attr("width", width)
                                .attr("height", height)
                                .append("g")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
                        }
                        var path = svg.selectAll("path").data(pie(_data));

                        path.enter().append("path")
                            .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
                            .attr("d", arc)
                            .each(function(d) {this._current = d;} );


                        var text  = svg.selectAll("text")
                                            .data(pie(_data));

                        text.append('text')
                            .attr("fill", "black")
                            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                            var c = arc.centroid(d),
                                x = c[0],
                                y = c[1],
                                h = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
                            return "translate(" + (x/h * labelr) +  ',' +
                                (y/h * labelr) +  ")"; 
                        })
                            .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                            // are we past the center?
                            return (d.endAngle + d.startAngle)/2 > Math.PI ?
                                "end" : "start";
                        })
                            .text(function (d) {
                            return d[0]+ " " + formatPercent(d[1]);
                            });



                path.transition()
                    .attrTween("d", arcTween)
                    .duration(750);

                path.exit().remove()



                function arcTween(a) {
                    var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
                    this._current = i(0);
                    return function(t) {
                        return arc(i(t));
                    };
                }

            });

            }
            return graph;
            }

            var updateFunction = updatePie();
            var container = d3.select("#chartDiv");

            function update(data) {
                container.datum(data).call(updateFunction);
            }

            var firstDataset = getChannelData("channelName1");

            update(firstDataset);

            document.getElementById("dropdown").addEventListener("click", reDrawChart);

            function reDrawChart() {
                var e = document.getElementById("dropdown");
                var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
                getChannelData("channelName2");
                var secondDataset = getChannelData(strUser);
                update(secondDataset);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no fiddle provided I haven't run the code, but it would probably be helpful to use enter and exit selections when adding the labels (this also prevents duplicate labels on updates).

To do so change the bit where you add the labels:

```
text
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  //the rest of your test attributes

text
  .exit()
  .remove();
```

Now that doesn't immediately solve your problem, but next step would be logging the enter selection. if the enter selection is empty you probably have a problem with the data you are binding to text (issue with what `pie(_data)` returns).

If the enter selection is coming through correctly and has the labels you want to add to the DOM it must be in the way you add the labels. This looks fine however so I assume it's a problem with the data you are binding.

If you could add a console log of `pie(_data)` and the label enter selection I'll be happy to help further.
(Or provide a fiddle with your problem).

Hope this helps.

Comment: the console log looks as follows:

Comment: Hi Anton, thanks for your help. Your comment helped a lot.  The console log looks as follows: {data: ["A", "0"], value: 0, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0, padAngle: 0} (for all countries in my dataset). This seems to be working fine. For the other countries the values are not 0 of course. What I additionally would need to know is How i could modify the dataset to look like this: {data: ["A", "0"],name: "A", value: 0, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0, padAngle: 0} and why my text transition isn't working. After adding the code you suggested, the values are shown. Thank you so much.

Comment: Re transition: Which part of you text do you want to animate? The position, generally the adding of the text?

Comment: actually both, the position when changing data, and the adding on load.

Comment: Try just adding a transition as the first element on your enter selection like so: text
  .enter().transition().duration(500)
  .append('text')
  //the rest of your test attributes

Comment: Otherwise I recommend asking it as a separate question as code snippets in comments are horrible ; )